# What is the path of the root directory on IIS server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm attempting to write to a logfile, but `File.Write(path, string)` is not giving me access.

This is the error message:

```
Access to the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\20130213190451765 49cb4a74-de61-49e5-93de-94d982073f89.txt' is denied.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is given via `Server.MapPath("~")`. I'd advise against making the root folder of your site writeable in most cases. Why not choose a different, isolated location and give write permission to your app pool identity for that location?

Comment: Aww come on. It would be a great Valentine's Day gift to a hacker to make your web site root read/write.